# bash + verify if file that ended with many combinations exists

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, regular-expression

we can have the `/tmp/file.1` or `/tmp/file.43.434` or `/tmp/file-hegfegf` , and so on

so how we can verify in bash if any `/tmp/file*` exists ?

we try as

```
[[ -f "/tmp/file*" ]] && echo "file exists"
```

but above not work

how to fix it?

Comment: If you use quotes, the literal "file*" is tested and returns false. If unquoted, the `file*` could expand to more than one arguments, which is not allowed for the `-f` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use either `find` or a `for` loop to identify this situation.

Example #1 with `find` (using GNU extensions to limit the search space):

```
# First try with no matching files
[ -n "$(find /tmp/file* -maxdepth 1 -type f -print -quit)" ] && echo yes || echo no    # "no"

# Create some matching files and try the same command once more
touch /tmp/file.1 /tmp/file.43.434 /tmp/file-hegfegf
[ -n "$(find /tmp/file* -maxdepth 1 -type f -print -quit)" ] && echo yes || echo no    # "yes"
```

Example #2 with `for` loop

```
found=
for file in /tmp/file*
do
    [ -f "$file" ] && found=yes && break
done
[ yes = "$found" ] && echo yes || echo no    # No files "no", otherwise "yes"
```

Comment: OP didn't specify if *file* is a regular file, though can be assumed.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I think an example of `[[ -f "/tmp/file*" ]]` makes it pretty clear they're considering only _files_

Comment: `set -- /tmp/file*; [ -e "$1" ]`

Comment: @roaima Ideed, I interpreted the question, not the example.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes also. I hadn't considered that, but I do see it's one of the suggestions on the proposed duplicate (not a bad match, by the way)